# Sample Space issue

Tags: probability

If Alex has two children and he truthfully answers yes to the question "Is at least one of your child a girl ?" what is the probability that both his children are girls.

**Process:-**

I have figured out that this is a question of conditional probability , so my earlier sample space ={Boy Girl, Boy Boy , Girl Girl} would be reduced to {Boy Girl, Girl Girl} and which would give me a probability of 1/2, but the answer given to this problem is 1/3

Upon looking at the solution provided I found that they took the initial sample space as {BG,GB,BB,GG} which has raised a question for me of why did they take BG and GB as separately 2 events

Comment: For the sample space that you introduced, which has three outcomes, you seem to be assuming that all three outcomes are equally likely. But that assumption isn't correct. The book's sample space, which contains four outcomes, has the advantage that all four outcomes are in fact equally likely.

Comment: @littleO do we need to always construct our sample space such that each event is equally likely ?

Comment: No, we just need to not base our calculations on that assumption if it isn’t true.